# Running a subscription each time user changes roles

Tags: meteor

I have some subscriptions I need to refresh when a user changes roles. Since the user now has a new role I need to republish the subscriptions as they take role into account. Here is what I'm attempting to do:

```
Tracker.autorun(function(){
    Meteor.users.find({_id: Meteor.userId()}, {fields: {"roles": 1}});
    console.log("You changed roles, republishing data");
    Meteor.subscribe('pendingUsers');
});
```

I'm using alanning:roles. It seems to work in some situations but not others. One situation that doesn't trigger this to run is when I alter the users roles from "meteor shell". What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you show your publish function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make something change within your `subscribe()`.  See [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe):

> However, if the next iteration of your run function subscribes to the same record set (same name and parameters), Meteor is smart enough to skip a wasteful unsubscribe/resubscribe.