# Meteor.subscribe is skipped, doesn’t work in Tracker.autorun

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

I’m using user’s profile to publish specific data to client.

However the subscribe doesn’t work and it’s killing me.

Although the Tracker.autorun() runs, the server doesn’t run any publish.

```
Tracker.autorun(function () {
   console.log(‘autorun is running');  
   console.log(Meteor.user()) //to be reactive to user's update
   Meteor.subscribe(“Lists”,{
    onStop:function() { 
        console.log('subscribe call back onStop'); 
        },
    onReady: function(){
        console.log('subscribe call back onReady'); 
    });
   console.log(Lists.find().count());
}

Meteor.publish('Lists', function(){
   console.log('publish is running’);
   var list = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId}).list; 
   return Lists.find({_id: {$in: list}}); 
}
```

p.s if I type Meteor.subscribe( “Lists”) in Chrome's console line, it works and server run publish normally.

p.s The Lists collection didn't change. Just publishing a different set. Is it the reason?

Thank for your reading.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running a subscription each time user changes roles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30284312/running-a-subscription-each-time-user-changes-roles)

Comment: I found the subscribe only runs at first time or reload page. It is amazingly skipped when autorun runs, no callback onReady or onStop appears. (Sorry I should add more details of callback)

Comment: I passed a variable, but it still not work.. I'm looking for what kinds of factors cause subscribe skip

Comment: Oh It runs if I pass a Random.id() !!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a close look at the docs for [subscribe](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe), you'll find this note in a section about reactive computations:

> However, if the next iteration of your run function subscribes to the same record set (same name and parameters), Meteor is smart enough to skip a wasteful unsubscribe/resubscribe.

So because you are always calling subscribe with the same arguments, meteor isn't actually restarting it. The trick is just to pass extra parameters to defeat this "optimization". For example:

```js
Tracker.autorun(function() {
  var user = Meteor.user();
  var list = user && user.list;
  if (!_.isEmpty(list)) {
    Meteor.subscribe('Lists', list, function() {
      console.log(Lists.find().count());
    });
  }
});
```

Here we are extracting the `list` variable from the user (assuming it's published) and using it as an extra parameter to force the subscription to rerun. If it isn't published, you could just use a random id like this:

```js
Tracker.autorun(function() {
  var user = Meteor.user();
  Meteor.subscribe('Lists', Random.id(), function() {
    console.log(Lists.find().count());
  });
});
```

This should also work but may be a little less efficient because it will fire whenever **any** property of the user changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should run the "console log" after the subscribe and the publish methods return something, if you do somenthing inmediatly is should not work because the server is not returning anything yet, add a callback to the subscription.

```
Tracker.autorun( function() {
 Meteor.subscribe( "List", function() {
  console.log( "okok" );
  // do your magic
 }
};
```

hope it help, sorry about my english =)

Comment: I added the callback and the client side showed the callback normally, but the server didn't republish and show console.log. The publish still skipped it...  Thank you anyway

Comment: I don't think it's how this works, publish is called once, it isn't triggered after data changes, maybe look at http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe_changes . Also you don't need to wrap subscribe in autorun, just put it somewhere in your code (or route in router)